# Write a function called reverse_str in C that takes a single char * parameter and reverses the string in place

Tags: c, string

I am new to c program,I tried to attempt an practice question as following guidelines.
Write a function called reverse_str in C that takes a single char * parameter and reverses the string in place. Thus, if the value of str is:

```
char str[] = "Let's meet l8r 2nite?";
```

Then after calling **reverse_str** the value of str should be:

```
"?etin2 r8l teem s'teL"
```

Remember, your function should match this prototype declaration:

```
void reverse_str(char *str);
```

Instructions: Do not assume that any library or header other than stdio.h has been included. Use only standard C (specifically, do not use any Microsoft specific functions). Do not print anything in your function. Your submission should only contain the reverse_str function and nothing else (specifically, do not include a main function).

i tried this solution at that website

```
void reverse_str(char* str)
{
    int i, slen = 0;
    while (str[slen] != '\0') 
    {
        slen++;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < (slen + 1) / 2; i++) 
    {
        str[i] += str[slen];
        str[slen] = str[i] - str[slen];
        str[i] = str[i] - str[slen--];
    }
}
```

but it giving me this type of message

> Sorry. Your solution is incorrect. Please try again. Feedback for your solution:
>
> Your function does not work as expected. Please check the following carefully:
>
> Does your function produce the output given in the problem? You should put your function in a full program, compile and run it and test it before submitting. (But submit only the function, not the full program.)
>
> Your submission should only contain the function, the full function, and no other extra code. Specifically, it should not contain the main function, or any other #included files
>
> Make sure that your submission does not contain any functions not found in the standard C library. Specifically, do not use any Microsoft specific functions.
>
> Do not include conio.h and do not use functions like getch.
> Make sure you do not print anything. No printf or putc or puts.

**can you tell me what will be the correct solution**

Comment: Start indenting your code. Then start debugging it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. [link](http://rsphinx.com/practice/C-Language/Function/) plz visit the site and try to attempt. If you succeed, post your code here, it will be very helpful @MichaelWalz

Comment: Use `slen--;` then swap values.

Comment: Needs something different in `i < (slen + 1) / 2` as `slen` is changing.

Answer (score 1):

At first: `i < (slen + 1) / 2` - why `+ 1` ? It should be just `i < (slen) / 2` because you need to iterate half the string in case of even length of the string and half-1 characters when length is odd (the middle charached doesn't have to be swapped with something because it is already on it's place - exact middle).

Now about `str[i] += str[slen];`, `str[i] - str[slen];` and `str[i] - str[slen--];` - here you 'substract' characters, so the result is invalid.

You need to simply swap characters something like this:

```
char swapCharacter = str[i];
str[i] = str[slen-i-1];
str[slen-i-1] = swapCharacter;
```